# PHP check if value in array of objects exists more than once

Tags: php

I've this array here with multiple object:

```
$batches = [
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'number' => 'ABC'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'number' => 'ABC'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'number' => 'DEF'
    ]
];
```

Now I need to know if there are any numbers that exists more than once. In this case its `ABC`.

I've tried using `array_sum` and `array_column` but this seems to only work with numbers:

```
$test = array_sum( array_column( $batches, 'number' ) );
```

Comment: Why would you use `array_sum()`? They're not numbers, you can't add them.

Comment: I thought it maybe counts the occurrences but I was wrong.

Comment: And even if they were numbers, how would that tell you if there are duplicates?

Comment: You're thinking of `array_count_values()`

Comment: @miken32 How does your duplicate answer the question. It's not about duplicates, it's about searching for a specific value.

Comment: @Barmar yes, pasted the wrong URL. Updated now

Comment: @miken32 I don't think that's right, either. This is looking in a specific key of associative arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_count_values()` to count the repetitions. Then you can filter this to just the ones with counts more than 1.

```
$results = array_keys(
    array_filter(array_count_values(array_column($batches, 'number')),
                 static function($count) { return $count > 1; }));
```

Comment: Awesome! That's what I was looking for! Thanks Barmar :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the benefit of declaring it static is.

Comment: Thats just how I learned it so I thought it might be correct. I think this is just a style decision.

Comment: From the documentation: **Anonymous functions may be declared statically. This prevents them from having the current class automatically bound to them.** Unless the code is inside a class, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now it makes sense.